# Nginx -- static file serving confusion with root & alias

Tags: nginx

I need to serve my app through my app server at `8080`, and my static files from a directory without touching the app server.

```
    # app server on port 8080
    # nginx listens on port 8123
    server {
            listen          8123;
            access_log      off;

            location /static/ {
                    # root /var/www/app/static/;
                    alias /var/www/app/static/;
                    autoindex off;
            }


            location / {
                    proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                    proxy_set_header        Host             $host;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            }
    }
```

Now, with this config, everything is working fine. Note that the `root` directive is commented out.

If I activate `root` and deactivate the `alias`, it stops working. However, when I remove the trailing `/static/` from `root`, it starts working again.

Can someone explain what's going on?

Answer (score 1442, accepted):

There is a very important difference between the `root` and the `alias` directives. This difference exists in the way the path specified in the `root` or the `alias` is processed.

`root`

- the `location` part is appended to `root` part
- final path = `root` + `location`

`alias`

- the `location` part is replaced by the `alias` part
- final path = `alias`

To illustrate:

Let's say we have the config

```
location /static/ {
    root /var/www/app/static/;
    autoindex off;
}
```

In this case the final path that Nginx will derive will be

```
/var/www/app/static/static
```

This is going to return `404` since there is no `static/` within `static/`

This is because the location part is appended to the path specified in the `root`. Hence, with `root`, the correct way is

```
location /static/ {
    root /var/www/app/;
    autoindex off;
}
```

On the other hand, with `alias`, the location part gets **dropped**. So for the config

```
location /static/ {
    alias /var/www/app/static/;
    autoindex off;           ↑
}                            |
                             pay attention to this trailing slash
```

the final path will correctly be formed as

```
/var/www/app/static
```

In a way this makes sense. The `alias` just lets you define a new path to represent an existing "real" path. The location part is that new path, and so it gets replaced with the real path. Think of it as a symlink.

Root, on the other hand is not a new path, it contains some information that has to be collated with some other info to make the final path. And so, the location part is used, not dropped.

#### *The case for trailing slash in `alias`*

There is no definitive guideline about whether a trailing slash is mandatory per [Nginx documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias), but a common observation by people here and elsewhere seems to indicate that it is.

A few more places have discussed this, not conclusively though.

https://serverfault.com/questions/376162/how-can-i-create-a-location-in-nginx-that-works-with-and-without-a-trailing-slas

https://serverfault.com/questions/375602/why-is-my-nginx-alias-not-working

Comment: The trailing slash on the alias path is essential!

Comment: This is all great (it helped me fix my config issues), but I wonder what logging settings people could use to help diagnose these kinds of problems?  Like, anything that would print to logs stuff like "received request for [...], matched by "location [...]" config block, searching directory [...]"

Comment: @Pistos: put `log_format scripts '$document_root | $uri | > $request';` into `http` section and `access_log /var/log/nginx/scripts.log scripts;` into `server` section of nginx config..

Comment: Thanks! Indeed the trailing slash is essential on the alias, otherwise i got `nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "alias" directive`, and the server went down during its restart.

Comment: @mafrosis Why is it essential?

Comment: @mafrosis I was going crazy trying to understand why the heck my configuration wasn't working. IMHO the answer by treecoder is absolutely **NOT** complete without clarifying that you must put a trailing `/` otherwise alias will not work.

Comment: Does the trailing slash you talk about have anything to with me getting a 404 on `/my/path` but a 200 on `/my/path/`?

Comment: Can you explain my observation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65651059/in-nginx-location-block-with-regex-match-the-entire-path-including-the-locatio), where the **entire path including the location part** is appended to the alias?

Answer (score 159):

as say as @treecoder

> In case of the `root` directive, full path is appended to the root including the location part, whereas in case of the `alias` directive, only the portion of the path NOT including the location part is appended to the alias.

A picture is worth a thousand words

for `root`:

[image]

for `alias`:

[image]

Comment: Should the first arrow in the second image be a "+"?

Comment: A picture is worth 0 words if it isn't made accessible for users with visual impairments

Answer (score 44):

In your case, you can use `root` directive, because `$uri` part of the `location` directive is the same with last `root` directive part.

> [Nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) advices it as well:
>   When location matches the last part of the directive’s value:
>
> ```
> location /images/ {
>     alias /data/w3/images/;
> }
> ```
>
> it is better to use the root directive instead:
>
> ```
> location /images/ {
>     root /data/w3;
> }
> ```

and `root` directive will append `$uri` to the path.

Comment: Why is it better? Docs don't say either.

Comment: The benefit that  I see is to avoid duplication of the $uri, /images in given example, when using alias

Answer (score 25):

Just a quick addendum to @good_computer's very helpful answer, I wanted to replace to root of the URL with a folder, but only if it matched a subfolder containing static files (which I wanted to retain as part of the path).

For example if file requested is in `/app/js` or `/app/css`, look in `/app/location/public/[that folder]`.

I got this to work using a regex.

```
 location ~ ^/app/((images/|stylesheets/|javascripts/).*)$ {
     alias /home/user/sites/app/public/$1;
     access_log off;
     expires max;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I know this is 3 years later, but could anyone explain if there is a performance and/or security tradeoff between using alias versus root?

Comment: @Mina It's better to use root if you can. (There's a comment in the docs http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#alias )

Comment: This is exactly what I came here for 

Comment: Both are safe, but be careful when using alias with location that doesn't end with /
It is a vulnerability https://github.com/yandex/gixy/blob/master/docs/en/plugins/aliastraversal.md

Answer (score 9):

`alias` is used to replace the location part path (LPP) in the request path, while the `root` is used to be prepended to the request path.

They are two ways to map the request path to the final file path.

`alias` could only be used in location block, and it will override the outside `root`.

`alias` and `root` cannot be used in location block together.

Answer (score 3):

```
server {
    server_name xyz.com;
    root /home/ubuntu/project_folder/;

    client_max_body_size 10M;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/project.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/project.error.log;

    location /static {
        index index.html;
    }

    location /media {
        alias /home/ubuntu/project/media/;
    }
}
```

Server block to live the static page on nginx.

Comment: Be careful when using alias with location that doesn't end with /

It is a vulnerability https://github.com/yandex/gixy/blob/master/docs/en/plugins/aliastraversal.md

Files from the project directory can be revealed using /media.. on request

Answer (score 3):

Though my answer is not needed, But I think It is necessary to add this, `root` and `alias` works differently when is come to regex.

```
 location ~ /static/my.png$ {
     alias /var/www/static/;
     access_log off;
     expires max;
 }
```

In this case the regex match is not going to add with alias, nginx will search only `/var/www/static/` not `/var/www/static/my.png`. You have to use regex capture.

```
 location ~ /static/my.png$ {
     root /var/www;
     access_log off;
     expires max;
 }
```

In this case the matched url going to add with root, nginx will search `/var/www/static/my.png`.

Answer (score 2):

In other words on keeping this brief: in case of `root`, location argument specified is part of **filesystem's path and URI** . On the other hand — for `alias` directive argument of  location statement is part of **URI only**

So, `alias` is a different name that maps certain URI to certain path in the filesystem, whereas `root` appends location argument to the root path given as argument to `root` directive.