# Nginx Grails - serve static files stored in multiple directories

Tags: tomcat, grails, nginx

Im working on a project on my local machine `Mac OSX 10.7.5` using :

- **Grails 2.2.2**
- **Grails resources plugin 1.1.6**
- **Nginx 1.4**

**//EDIT**

There is a pretty much similar question asked [here](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/grails-2-0rc1-resources-pre-compilation-td4084020.html) but unfortunately with no answer..

**//END EDIT**

I have 3 directories containing some images that are located **outside** the `web-app` dir.
(as theses directories my contains a lot of images we don't want them to be into the `'<project>.war'` )

```
/Users/lorenzo/grails/projects/avatars/
/Users/lorenzo/grails/projects/posters/
/Users/lorenzo/grails/projects/waveforms/
```

All other **images/js/css** are stored under the `web-app` directory in different `sub-directories.`

```
web-app/images/home/
web-app/images/icons/
web-app/images/skins/
...

web-app/audioplayer/images/
web-app/audiomenu/icons/
...

web-app/js/angular/
web-app/js/angular/controllers/
...

web-app/audioplayer/js/
web-app/audioplayer/css/
web-app/audiomenu/css/
...
```

I have set up the `nginx.conf` as follow:

```
server {
    server_name localhost;
    listen 8080;
    access_log /usr/local/logs/access.log;

    root /Users/lorenzo/grails/projects/soundshare/grails-app;
    index /home;

    location @tomcat {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @tomcat;
    }

    location /avatars {  
        root /Users/lorenzo/grails/projects;
    }   
    location /waveforms {
        root /Users/lorenzo/grails/projects;
    }   

    location /posters {
        root /Users/lorenzo/grails/projects;
    }   


    # what should I do here ????
    location ~* ^.+\.(js|css)$ {
        root /;
    }

}
```

The Grails resource plugin put the static file into a "temporary" directory called `static` so when the browser make a request to the server some `js/css` are located at

```
http://localhost/static/bundle-bundle_project_head.css
http://localhost/static/bundle-bundle_application_js_defer.js
```

Some others that are coming from grails plugin set in `BuildConfig.groovy`
eg: compile ":jquery-ui:1.8.24"

are locate

```
http://localhost/static/plugins/jquery-1.8.3/js/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js
```

With the actual nginx config I get an **nginx error**

```
/static/bundle-bundle_application_js_defer.js" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

Of course if I call it directly with port 8081 it is working. Tomcat is serving it.

```
http://localhost:8081/static/bundle-bundle_application_js_defer.js
```

But If I call it with 8080

I get the error. /`static/bundle-bundle_application_js_defer.js" failed (2: No such file or directory)`

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? It appears the call to /static/ is being directed to port 8080 and not 8081. [This user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631933/nginx-static-file-serving-confusion-with-root-alias?rq=1) had some issues with ROOT and ALIAS resolution that may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to create a location block for static resources explicitly in NGINX as an alias. This should match where grails houses the plugin static resources. 
Under location add

`location /static {
    alias /Users/lorenzo/grails/projects/STATIC/; 
}`

to your nginx.conf file.