# How to serve a directory of static files at a certain location path with nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have files at `/Users/me/myproject` and I want to serve them at `http://stuff.dev/something` using a simple nginx config. In the `/Users/me/myproject` folder is something like:

```
index.html
scripts/
    app.js
styles/
    style.css
```

So I really want to be able to access `http://stuff.dev/something`, `http://stuff.dev/something/scripts/app.js` etc.

In my nginx conf I have this:

```
server {
  listen      80;
  server_name stuff.dev;

  location /something {
    index  index.html;
    root /Users/me/myproject;
  }
}
```

This doesn't work (I get a 404 if I try to go to those above URLs), however if I try the exact same set up but using `location / {` instead of `location /something {`, it works fine. How can I serve this directory of files statically but at a path instead of at the location root? Do I *have* to have the files in a folder called "something" like `/Users/me/myproject/something` for this to work? If so is there a way around that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I tried this out on my VPS, and using the [`alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) command worked for me:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name   something.nateeagle.com;

  location /something {
    alias /home/neagle/something;
    index index.html index.htm;
  }
}
```

Comment: That did it! Still confused why `root` works differently here, but this is what I need. Thanks Nate!

Comment: Not totally sure, I was just going by documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root

"A path to the file is constructed by merely adding a URI to the value of the root directive. If a URI has to be modified, the alias directive should be used."

Glad this helped!

Comment: Hmm, that actually does make sense now that I think about it. Thanks!

Comment: For further reference:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631933/nginx-static-file-serving-confusion-with-root-alias

Comment: exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can accomplish this with the [try_files](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html) directive, something like this should work:

```
server {
  listen      80;
  server_name stuff.dev;

  location /something {
    root /Users/me/myproject;
    index  index.html;

    try_files /Users/me/myproject/$uri /Users/me/myproject/$uri/ =404
  }
}
```

That *might* require you to shove files under **/Users/me/myproject/something**, and if you can't get away with that, you'll need to try something like the following for the location:

```
  location ~ /something(.*) {
    root /Users/me/myproject;
    index  index.html;

    try_files /Users/me/myproject$1 /Users/me/myproject$1/ =404
  }
```

Comment: Interesting... I'll try this in a minute, curious what the point of "root" is if you have to mention the whole path anyway... I assumed try_files would be relative to the scoped root value...

Comment: Looking at this more, it might be a problem with openresty + os x el capitan and how it's all set up. :(