# Nginx, uwsgi, django, ubuntu 16 issue w/ static files

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi

I am using Nginx, uwsgi, django and Ubuntu 16.04 and getting 404 on all my static files. When I look at nginx's error.log  it's adding an extra /static in front of the actual file location:

404 Not found:
/home/jsmith/firstproj/static_cdn/static/css/bootstrap.css

Actual location:
/home/jsmith/firstproj/static_cdn/css/bootstrap.css

I'm not sure why it's adding the /static in front of the /css/bootstrap.css.  Here are my config files:

## /var/log/nginx/error.log

```
2016/07/20 17:34:25 [error] 4424#4424: *22 open() "/home/jsmith/firstproj/static_cdn/static/css/bootstrap.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: , server: , request: "GET /static/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1", host:
```

## /home/jsmith/firstproj/src/blogs/settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn")

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    ]
```

## /etc/nginx/sites-available/firstproj

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static {
        root /home/jsmith/firstproj/static_cdn;
    }

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/run/uwsgi/firstproj.sock;
    }
}
```

## /etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor service
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c 'mkdir -p /run/uwsgi; chown jsmith:www-data /run/uwsgi'
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

## /etc/uwsgi/sites/firstproj.ini

```
[uwsgi]
project = firstproj
base = /home/jsmith

chdir = %(base)/%(project)/src
home = %(base)/.virtualenvs/%(project)
module = %(project).wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 5

socket = /run/uwsgi/%(project).sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in "static" configuration of nginx. This code fixes the problem

```
location /static {
    alias /home/jsmith/firstproj/static_cdn;
}
```

Check this post [Nginx -- static file serving confusion with root & alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631933/nginx-static-file-serving-confusion-with-root-alias)