# Nginx error 404 when using autoindex

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm completely new to nginx. I've installed nginx on windows pc.

What I want to do is server a list of files in `D:\` on `localhost:8082/list`.

If I use the following conf:

```
server {
    listen       8082;

    location / {
        root D:/;
        autoindex on;
    }
}
```

I can correctly see what i want on `localhost:8082`. But if I change it to:

```
server {
    listen       8082;

    location /list {
        root D:/;
        autoindex on;
    }
}
```

The page `localhost:8082/list` gives a 404 error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you need is `alias` instead of `root`.

```
server {
    listen       8082;

    location /list {
        alias D:/; ##### use alias, not root
        autoindex on;
    }
}
```

See [Nginx -- static file serving confusion with root & alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631933/nginx-static-file-serving-confusion-with-root-alias)