# Nginx is serving the default content instead of my content

Tags: nginx, configuration, server, configuration-files, nginx-location

I have a `nginx version: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)` running on `Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS`.

I use `nginx` to serve static files, bundles generated by `webpack`, but that's irrelenvant.

What I want to achieve is this:

On `example.com` I want to serve `/home/bundles/main/index.html`. I can do this.

On `projects.example.com/project_1` I want to serve `/home/bundles/project_1/index.html`.

On `projects.example.com/project_2` I want to serve `/home/bundles/project_2/index.html`.

The last two, I can't do. When I go to `projects.example.com/project_1` or `projects.example.com/project_2` I am served the default nginx page.

To make things more confusing `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` is entirely commented out.

Additionally, if in the `location` block of `projects.example.com` I replace, for example, `project_1` with `/`, I will be served that specific project, but then I will have no way of serving the other.

Bellow, I will show you my nginx configuration

---

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        root /home/bundles/main;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        root /home/bundles/main;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    ssl_certificate ...
    ssl_certificate_key ...
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name projects.example.com;

    location /project_1 {
        root /home/bundles/project_1;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location /project_2 {
        root /home/bundles/project_2;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name projects.example.com;

    location /project_1 {
        root /home/bundles/project_1;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location /project_2 {
        root /home/bundles/project_2;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    ssl_certificate ...
    ssl_certificate_key ...
}
```

---

Thank you for your help!

---

**EDIT**

### My Answer

The solution I found was to change the `root` with `alias`.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        root /home/bundles/main;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        root /home/bundles/main;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    ssl_certificate ...
    ssl_certificate_key ...
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name projects.example.com;

    location /project_1 {
        alias /home/bundles/project_1;
        index index.html;
    }

    location /project_2 {
        alias /home/bundles/project_2;
        index index.html;
    }

    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name projects.example.com;

    location /project_1 {
        alias /home/bundles/project_1;
        index index.html;
    }

    location /project_2 {
        alias /home/bundles/project_2;
        index index.html;
    }

    ssl_certificate ...
    ssl_certificate_key ...
}
```

The solution is based on these two answers. The first [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/406168/nginx-location-pathing-issue) showing how to solve the problem and the second [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631933/nginx-static-file-serving-confusion-with-root-alias#10647080) providing a explanation as to why `alias` works and `root` does not.

To quote @treecoder

> In case of the root directive, full path is appended to the root including the location part, whereas in case of the alias directive, only the portion of the path NOT including the location part is appended to the alias.

In my particular case, this would translate like this;

With `root`, the path `nginx` would try to access would be `/home/bundles/project_1/project_1`.

With `alias` it accesses the correct path, `/home/bundles/project_1`.

Going back one level, for example, saying:

`root /home/bundles/` is not really a option either. That is because my projects are not actually called `project_1` and `project_2`. The actual structure is more similar to this.

In `/bundles` I have the directories `project_a` and `project_b`. I want to route `project_1` to the `project_a` directory and `project_2` to the `project_b` directory.

That is why I used `alias`.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
location /project_1 {
    root /home/bundles/project_1;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

So the `root` is only defined for URIs that begin with `/project_1`. For any other URI, the default `root` will be used.

If you present the URI `/project_1/` (with a trailing `/`), assuming that the [default `index` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index) is in force, `nginx` should return your `/project_1/index.html` content.

However, the URI `/project_1` is not found - so `/index.html` is returned instead. The URI `/index.html` does not begin with `/project_1`, so the default root is used.

---

If you want the URI `/project_1` to work as expected, and the default action to go to the project's `index.html` file, change the `try_files` directive.

```
location /project_1 {
    root /home/bundles/project_1;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /project_1/index.html;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.

---

As both projects share a common root, you could simplify as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name projects.example.com;

    root /home/bundles
    index index.html;

    location /project_1 {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /project_1/index.html;
    }
    location /project_2 {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /project_2/index.html;
    }
    location / {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I added the `index` directive to avoid relying on the default value (which is the same), and a `location` block to deny access to areas outside of the projects.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem...and it turned out, for me, that the default site that was "overtaking" my desired secondary site and serving the default files...well it allowed IP6 requests, and my new site didn't.

Here's an example of my access.log:

```
::1 - - [05/Sep/2020:15:05:16 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 40 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36"
```

Notice the `::1` bit? That's an IP6 request that I guess my browser was defaulting to. So I just made sure to enable local IP6 requests for the site in question in my site config file by changing:

```
listen 80;
server_name example.local;
```

to:

```
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name example.local;
```

That was it.