# Nginx - change project root directory in especific route

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I'm settings two projects in the same domain, a first project is a ReactJS project for my front end and a second project for my API in symfony.

I need config the virtual host of nginx so that my domain www.example.com go to my reactjs roject and www.example.com/api go to my symfony project.

The others router example www.example.com/register or www.example.com/login must be go to reactjs project and the sub folder in www.example.com/api/* go to my symfonys project.

I use Ubuntu 16.04. I've tried te next config

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location /api {
                root /var/www/symfony/public;
                try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;

       }

       location / {
               root /var/www/reactjs/build;
               index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

               try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

        location ~* \.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        }


      error_log /var/log/nginx/Inno_FRT__error.log;
      access_log /var/log/nginx/Inno_FRT__access.log;
}
```

But this not work.

I have tried many different variations of the above without success.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `root /var/www/symfony/public;` inside `location /api`, it's going to look in `root /var/www/symfony/public/api`.  You probably want [alias](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias).  Try this:

```
location /api/ {
    alias /var/www/symfony/public;
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

For an explanation of why this is necessary, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10647080/1188377).

Also, you probably want `location /api/`, not `location /api`.  Nginx does prefix matching, so `location /api` would match `/apifoobar`.