# Cannot upload media files in Django production to external folder

Tags: django, nginx, django-media

I have an issue on my Django production server.
When I try to upload images, they always go to the `app/media/` folder.
However I want them to be uploaded to `/mnt/data`.
In the admin panel, when I upload the image, it is always uploading in the `app/media/` folder.
I tried adjusting the Nginx config file and the settings.py, but I guess I am lost.

Here is my Nginx configuration:

```
     location /static/ {
            root /home/somthing/something/;
        }
        location /media/ {
        root /mnt/data/;
        }
```

and the Settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

    # Media files

    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

    MEDIA_ROOT = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
    )
```

and in my model this is how I create the image:

```
    pictures = models.ImageField(
            upload_to='postings/',
            verbose_name=_('Posting_picture'),
            blank=True, null=True,
            validators=[validate_image],
        )
```

I guess following this configuration, the uploaded picture is supposed to be in `mnt/data/media/postings`.

The media folder on the `mnt/data/` is `chmod 777`, I did it when I lost hope in writing/reading the folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently  you are uploading to:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
)
```

Basically means:

```
/path/to/project/media
```

In your case it should be:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/mnt/data'
```

Comment: Thank you, do you have any idea about the permissions of the folder? I want to stay away from the 777 permission.

Comment: 760 would work for nginx. Nginx only needs read access. So 760 is enough

Comment: sorry again, but now I have another issue coming: the files are uploaded to mnt/data/postings but they are read from mnt/data/media/postings.

Comment: Sorry i couldn't get you.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out, Debendera was right for the path, but the Nginx configuration was wrong. I changed it to :

```
location /media/ {
    alias /mnt/data/;
    }
```

and then it worked. If I am not mistaken, it was better to use alias instead of root.
This is my reference: [Nginx -- static file serving confusion with root & alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631933/nginx-static-file-serving-confusion-with-root-alias)