# Serve web app using custom URL path using NGINX

Tags: angularjs, angular, nginx

I have an Angular app and I want to serve it locally using NGINX (on Windows). The app works if I just go to `http://localhost`, but I want to serve my app using `http://localhost/my/ui` as the base path. This is where I ran out of ideas. I started from this:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        root html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
    }
}
```

I copied the dist folder to the NGINX's html folder to make things easier. The `index.html` file looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular-AngularJS hybrid thingie</title>
    <base href="/">

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
</head>

<body ng-cloak>
    <app></app>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried playing around with the `location` and `base href`, setting one or the other to `/my/ui`, or even both, but I just get a 404.

Answer (score 0):

If your Angular App are just plain files, try to put them into the nginx-root subfolder root/my/ui. Setting the `<base href=".">` instead of "/" will allow all links to resources resolve as relative path to http://localhost/my/ui

Answer (score 0):

Please note that if there are several matching location blocks `nginx` selects the one with the longest prefix. The location block with only `/` provides the shortest prefix, of length one, and so only if all other location blocks fail to provide a match, this block will be used.

You need to change:

```
location / {
        root html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
    }
```

To this:

```
location /my/ui {
        root html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
    }
```

Comment: This works, but I just noticed that if I try to navigate to another page, let's say `/my/ui/page`, I am redirected to `/page`, is there some way of keeping that base path for all pages?

Comment: @Xzenon yeah ! First, create the /data/www directory and put an index.html file, and now change to location /my/ui {
    root /data/www;
}

Comment: You can also find a lot of information regarding your seconds question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631933/nginx-static-file-serving-confusion-with-root-alias