# nginx serving static content at a path

Tags: nginx

I have nginx running and want to serve an static application at the URL `https://example.com/myapp`.

I have a `server` block like so:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name example.com;

  root /var/www/html;

  location /myapp/ {
    root /home/tri/myapp/dist;
    rewrite ^/myapp/?(.*)$ /$1 break;
  }
}
```

I expect that by going to `https://example.com/myapp`, it will serve the `index.html` file, but that's not the case.

If I go to `https://example.com/myapp/index.html`, the file **is** served correctly. However, if I just go to `https://example.com/myapp`, I get this error in nginx:

```
2020/03/28 15:17:40 [error] 27905#27905: *11410 open() "/var/www/html/index.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 73.119.123.242, server: example.com, request: "GET /myapp/ HTTP/2.0", host: "example.com"
```

So for some reason, it's falling back to the default `root` directive.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure why my original configuration doesn't work, but thanks to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10647080/1368032, I switched to using `alias`, and it's now working for me (without the rewrite):

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name example.com;

  root /var/www/html;

  location /myapp/ {
    alias /home/tri/myapp/dist/;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this config

```
 location /myapp {

        try_files $uri $uri/ /home/tri/myapp/dist/index.html?$args;
        }
```

Comment: That did not work. I get the same error. It keeps going back to the default root.

Answer (score -1):

Your location “/myapp/“ won’t match “/myapp” without the trailing “/“ - you probably want to tweak the location value to make that optional, but I’m not near a computer where I can verify the correct syntax just at the moment.

Comment: I have tried it with the trailing slash as well, same result.