# how to specify nginx nested location in another directory

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I have a config that looks like:

```
server {
 listen 80;
 root /pubStuff;
 ...stuff...
 location /something {
  root /app/something
 }
}
```

The intention is, that while I can access stuff in the door of the server using example.com/ or with whatever directory/files location in /pubStuff, IF someone were to request example.com/something, or example.com/something/something.here.zip, they would get it!

When I try to go for example.com/something, I get a 404 not found error!
In error log it says:
14#14: *15409 open() "/app/something/something" failed (2: no such file or directory)....

I dont understand why does it affix a second "something", when I asked for only `example.com/something`, which should show me the content of `/app/something` as configured above, right?

I read the documentation on http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location but it is rather focused on the prefix matching stuff, not explaining whats wrong in my use case.

Based on stackoverflow suggestions, I tried the solution at [Nginx -- static file serving confusion with root & alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631933/nginx-static-file-serving-confusion-with-root-alias)

basically, it seems that only should only specify root `/app/`, and that it would go to /app/something/something.zip, but error log says it tries `/pubStuff/something/something.zip`, totally ignoring the root directive for `/something`.

Comment: Did you actually try the `Alias` solution from the other answer you have linked? Mind the difference between `Root` and `Alias`.

Comment: Try: `root /app;` - see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root).

Comment: @RichardSmith you are correct, along with removing the = in location, adding a trailing slash. Would you like to create an answer based on that? since your solution worked?