# How do I configure nginx to serve files with a prefix?

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, istio, nginx-location

I am trying to host static files in kubernetes with an nginx container, and expose them on a private network with istio.

I want the root of my server to exist at `site.com/foo`, as I have other applications existing at `site.com/bar`, `site.com/boo`, etc.

My istio virtual service configuration:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: cluster-foo
  namespace: namespace
spec:
  gateways:
  - cluster-gateway
  hosts:
  - site.com
  http:
  - match:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      uri:
        prefix: /foo
    route:
    - destination:
        host: app.namespace.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
```

All of my static files exist in the directory `/data` on my nginx container. My nginx config:

```
events {}
http {
    server {
        root /data;

        location /foo {
            autoindex on;
        }
    }
}
```

Applying this virtual service, and a kube deployment that runs an nginx container with this config, I get a nginx server at `site.com/foo` that serves all of the static files in `/data` on the container. All good. The problem is that the autoindexing that nginx does, does not respect the prefix `/foo`. So all the file links that nginx indexes at `site.com/foo`, look like this:
`site.com/page.html`, rather than `site.com/foo/page.html`. Furthermore, when I put `site.com/foo/page.html` in my browser manually, `site.com/foo/page.html` is displayed correctly, So I know that nginx is serving it in the correct location, just the links that it is indexing are incorrect.

Is there any way to configure nginx autoindex with a prefix?

Comment: Try adding a trailing slash to your location definition: `location /foo/ {...}`

Comment: Kubernetes seems to not like that. When I try to apply the deployment, the container enters a crash loop.

Comment: I meant in NGINX config but forget it anyway. Can you show how your broken links look like? Are they absolute ('/some/path') or relative ('some/path')?

Comment: Have you tried to use [alias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10647080) instead of root? I have tried with below server `http {
      server {
          listen       80;
          location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
          location /a {
            alias   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  page.html page.htm;
            autoindex on;
        }` And as there is no page.html it shows me `Index of /a/` when i put `site.com/a` in my browser.

Comment: @anemyte I meant that I added that location definition to my nginx.conf, but when I then applied the deployment in my kube cluster, the pod entered a crash loop. I am not sure what you mean by are the links absolute. The link addresses are `site.com/link.html` rather than the desired `site.com/foo/link.html`