# FASTApi and nginx missing static path

Tags: python, css, windows, nginx, fastapi

I run python FASTapi web-app on the server using `nginx` and all works correctly excepting .css style.

When I open app on the server where I host it - all formattings are correct, but when I tried to open app from another PC I lose all formats.

I have following folders:

```
+---static
|   +---css
|   \---images
+---templates
|   +---admin
|   +---auth
|   \---user
app.py
```

And in the nginx config file, I have the following setup

```
location /static {
# path for static files
root "C:/robots/poc_app";
}
```

How to setup nginx for pick up .css file?

Comment: Aren't you missing `/static` in your path for static files in your nginx configuration? i.e. it should point to the `static` directory inside your project?

Comment: I have the ```root``` and ```/static``` and finally it will be concatenated as ```root/static``` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631933/nginx-static-file-serving-confusion-with-root-alias)